# Prestashop Hide products from some cities

Tags: prestashop

i need to hide some products from some specific cities, when user reach first time my store i need them to choose there location (city), and then filters the product listing so as only products from this city appear.
By the way i'm a beginner in prestashop but i understand MVC pattern.
Thank you very much

Comment: Are the products only linked to one city?

Comment: PrestaShop version? 
it would be better by zip code?

Answer (score 0):

If you have only a few cities, I would create a category called "city", with subcategories for each city and link your products to those categories.

When a user select his city, he is redirected to the city corresponding category page and only sees the corresponding products.

If this does not fit your needs, then please edit your question by adding more informations.

Comment: greate IDEA... I was also going to suggest the same.